# Compose n functions where the innermost function expects multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to perform function composition like this:

```
f(g(...(z(x) (y));
```

I have already `compn`:

```
const id = x => x;

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const foldr = f => acc => xs =>
 xs.reduceRight((acc, x, i) => f(x) (acc, i), acc);

const compn = foldr(comp) (id);
```

I tried to derive the desired function from `compn`, but failed. All I've got is a hideous wrapper function that applies the composition accordingly:

```js
// generic functions

const id = x => x;

const last = xs => xs[xs.length - 1];

const init = xs => xs.slice(0, -1);

const sqr = x => x * x;

const inc = x => x + 1;

const sub = y => x => x - y;

const uncurry = f => (y, x) => f(x) (y);

const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

const foldr = f => acc => xs =>
 xs.reduceRight((acc, x, i) => f(x) (acc, i), acc);


// derived functions

const compn = foldr(comp) (id);


// wrapper function

const compn2 = fs => x => compn([...init(fs), last(fs) (x)]);


// arbitrary computation

const f = uncurry(compn2([sqr, inc, sub]));


console.log(f(5, 2)); // yields 16
```

Is there a way to derive `compn2` from `compn` or from other combinators?

Comment: from what I can tell you're trying something that simply won't work in the current form. Fold only accepts one argument. The only way you could work around that restriction is to provide a `foldrn` (or `foldr2`). Unfortunately this makes things start to really get difficult. The easiest way I see is to manually uncurry the "innermost" function and only **then** start folding, which is exactly what you did here...

Answer (score 1):

First, there's something weird happening here

> ```
> const f = uncurry(compn2([sqr, inc, sub]));
> console.log(f(5, 2)); // yields 16
> ```

I would assume that this composition is doing this

```
sqr (inc (sub (5) (2)))
// sqr (inc (2 - 5))
// sqr (inc (-3))
// sqr (-2)
// => 4
```

But upon closer inspect, it's because your `uncurry` function is unconventionally flipping the arguments

> ```
> const uncurry = f => (y, x) => f(x) (y);
> ```

Nevermind that tho, we don't have to agree on it. I'll show you a way to solve your problem without even depending on it.

---

I'm going to introduce a function `papply` which procedurally applies a curried function

```js
const papply = f => ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined ? f : papply (f(x)) (xs)

console.log(papply (x => y => y - x) ([2,5])) // 3
// (x => y => y - x) (2) (5)
// (y => y - 2) (5)
// 5 - 2
// => 3
```

---

I'm also going to introduce a dramatically simplified `compn` – there's nothing wrong with yours, but it will help reduce some of the complexity of the example I provide.

```js
const compn = ([f,...fs]) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : f(compn (fs) (x))

const inc = x => x + 1

const f = compn ([inc, inc, inc])

console.log(f(3))
// compn ([inc, inc, inc]) (3)
// inc (compn ([inc,inc]) (3))
// inc (inc (compn ([inc]) (3)))
// inc (inc (inc (compn ([]) (3))))
// inc (inc (inc (3)))
// inc (inc (4))
// inc (5)
// => 6
```

---

OK, let's get to it then !

```js
const sqr = x => x * x

const inc = x => x + 1

const sub = y => x => x - y

const compn = ([f,...fs]) => x =>
  f === undefined ? x : f(compn (fs) (x))

const papply = f => ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined ? f : papply (f(x)) (xs) 

const f = compn([sqr, inc, papply(sub)])

console.log(f([2, 5]));
// sqr (inc (papply (sub) ([2,5]))
// sqr (inc (papply (sub (2)) ([5])))
// sqr (inc (papply (x => x - 2) ([5])))
// sqr (inc (papply (5 - 2) ([])))
// sqr (inc (papply (3) ([])))
// sqr (inc (3))
// sqr (4)
// => 16
```

---

Of course it requires that the function is applied a bit differently ...

```
// this
f([2,5])

// instead of
f(5,2)
```

I don't think that change will bother you much tho, especially considering every other function of yours (including `compn`) is manually curried. This stays true to calling all functions with one arg. If multiple values are required, a tuple is provided – or in this case, an Array, as Tuple is absent in JS.

It's an interesting question and I think you had an interesting approach. The complexity ultimately steered me to thinking about a different solution. Just my 2 cents, hope it helped some ^_^

Comment: It is helpful to consider the problem under a different angle, thank you!